# How do you change the text in the modal dialog button ("...") on a PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am using a `System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid` in a WPF application. The `SelectedObject` contains a collection property, which currently displays as `"(Collection)"` in the property grid with a `...` button to its right.

How would one change the text on the `...` button?

[image: Property Grid with the Button to be Renamed]

Comment: What exactly are you looking to accomplish? That button is because of a [`UITypeEditor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd3kt7d5.aspx) available for collection types. Are you looking to provide your own custom editor for a collection of vehicles?

Comment: Yes, and rename "..." button into "+" button :)

Comment: [I believe your options are `...` or a down arrow.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditoreditstyle.aspx)

Comment: No, no :) I want to rename "..." text into "+" text

Comment: I understand your request. What I'm trying to say is using the built-in `PropertyGrid`, you do not have the ability to change the text on that button. Are you willing to consider a [WPF implementation of the property grid](http://wpg.codeplex.com/) which allows more customization?

Comment: Thanks, but license is not suitable :(

Answer (score -1):

Give the PropertyGrid a name in xaml using

```
x:Name="ButtonName"
```

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking. He wants to change the Text on the WinForms `PropertyGrid`s "open a property editor" window button, say for a Collection.

Comment: Maybe if he spoke in clear English then no one would have a problem understanding what hes asking